# Getting ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table after renaming model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I had previously named my model incorrect as "Companies". Instead of renaming it, I renamed all references, dropped the database and recreated everything by rerunning the migrations. I'm able to see the table recreated as "Company" from SQLite explorer but when I run Company.new through the irb, I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'companies'
from /Users/emzy/rails/blah/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:295:in `table_structure'
from /Users/emzy/rails/blah/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:186:in `columns'
from /Users/emzy/rails/blah/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/base.rb:680:in `columns'
from /Users/emzy/rails/blah/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:284:in `attributes_from_column_definition'
from /Users/emzy/rails/blah/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:62:in `attributes_from_column_definition'
from /Users/emzy/rails/blah/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/base.rb:1395:in `initialize'
from (irb):1:in `new'
from (irb):1
from /Users/emzy/rails/blah/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /Users/emzy/rails/blah/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/emzy/rails/blah/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure where the reference for 'companies' is coming from - I can't find any references within the project's directory. All the ymls, etc. look fine.

Controller:

```
class CompanyDirectoryController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_admin, :only => [:new, :create, :edit]
  def new
    @company = Company.new
    @company.companylinks.build
  end
```

Model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :fullname, :detailed_description, :product_info, :cat_tags, :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :fullname
  has_many :companylinks, :class_name => 'CompanyLinks',
                           :foreign_key => "pid",
                           :dependent => :destroy
  has_attached_file :company_photo, 
                    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",
                                 :thumb => "100x100>" }
  attr_accessor :photo_file_name
  attr_accessor :photo_content_type
  attr_accessor :photo_file_size
  attr_accessor :photo_updated_at

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :companylinks,
                                :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Routes:
    `resources :company, :controller => :company_directory`

Why is it still looking for `companies` instead of `Company` ? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table name ActiveRecord is looking up for the model Company is companies. Rails uses inflections to pluralize the name of the model to form the name of the table to query in the database. If you want to rename your table or have to work with a legacy database, you can use set_table_name in your model to set the table name.

UPDATE: There are some other useful tips at [the rails wiki](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/howtouselegacyschemas).

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that the table names should be the singular like the Models.

Comment: If you can get a copy of Agile Web Development with Rails from Pragmatic Programmers, it'll be a good read to get a grasp on the key rails concepts as well as some of the good software design principles.